# debugging when forking processes in Raspbian

Tags: c, linux, raspbian, glibc

I'm currently trying to get to run a piece of code in pure C on Raspbian Buster (uname -a: Linux raspberrypi 5.4.79-v7l+ #1373 SMP Mon Nov 23 13:27:40 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux)

The code compiles using a simple Makefile.

```
CFLAGS  =  $(DEBUG) -Wall $(INCLUDE) -Winline -pipe 
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/include

SRCS = $(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard *.c)

LDFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS    = -lwiringPi -lgeniePi -lm -lrt
LIBS = -lc -lpthread


DEMOHEADER = ./geniePi.h
DEMOSRCS = ./demo1.c
DEMOLIB = /usr/local/lib/libgeniePi.so 


all: applic 
applic:  $(SRCS) 
    $(CC) -ggdb -g $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

In the debugger I can see, that it enters the main function and then crashes when using the `fork()` command

```
int main(void) {

  /* Our process ID and Session ID */
  pid_t pid, sid;

  /* Fork off the parent process */
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ...
```

The error message is

```
Started new gdb process, pid 6558
The program is not being run.
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/nptl/pt-fork.c
Fetching assembly since file is missing
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/posix/../sysdeps/nptl/fork.c
Fetching assembly since file is missing
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/csu/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/aeabi_read_tp.S
Fetching assembly since file is missing
Fetching assembly since file is missing
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/nptl/register-atfork.c
Fetching assembly since file is missing
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/nptl/../malloc/dynarray-skeleton.c
```

When trying with a minimal example, I noticed that it is not specific for fork.. here printf can not be loaded

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello");
    pid_t pid, sid;

    /* Fork off the parent process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
      exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/stdio-common/printf.c
Fetching assembly since file is missing
```

Any ideas what could go wrong here or how I can find out more about the error?

Comment: *The code compiles using a simple Makefile.*  What code compiles?  If your car doesn't run, do you take a picture of it, bring the picture of your car to a repair shop, show someone the picture, and ask them what's wrong with it?  ***Post your code***.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ok maybe I was not clear enough about the code shown. The lines above are actually the first ones in main, I added the signature to make this clear. In the debugger I can enter main and it crashes right away on fork().

Comment: How did you install your toolchain on the Raspbian? I'd assume `sudo apt install gcc gdb` which should lead to a working setup.

Comment: actually the gcc and gdb came with the build-essential package, so yes, using sudo apt install build-essential

Comment: Please try to **run** a hello world program without the debugger. Then run it with the debugger. Then add `fork`. `File not found: /build/glibc-FUvrFr/glibc-2.28/stdio-common/printf.c` is a perfectly normal debugger message. You don't have the source of the C standard library. That's what the debugger is telling you, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems to me, that I was misunderstanding the Debugger output. The Debugger output was just telling me that there were no sources for the libc available. The program went on and crashed at another point. But due to the fork at the very beginning I was not able to set anymore breakpoints or step through the program, the debugger was not tracking the second process. For the moment I'm debugging without forking another process, I'll check how I can do this in my debugger.

Edit:
Later I found the solution in setting "set follow-fork-mode child" as an init command to be sent to gdb in my debugger settings